Apex Oracle: multi-column popup lov
I have a multi-column popup LOV based on the query:
SELECT name d,
       id  r,
       code d2
FROM   employees
WHERE  codes IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI')
ORDER BY name

When retrieving its selected value, is it possible to grab both of the display values, d and d2?

I don't understand the question. Could you illustrate it with a screenshot? Edit it (in Paint or whichever tool you use) to show what you have now, and what you'd want to get.

If you want to get the name and code when you select from an LOV, the name you selected, where do you want to store it, in a text field?
There is already a setting for this available here, under Additional Outputs:

In the image above, note the help message and the mapping I have. Here I am retrieving all values of the field and mapping them to page items. Here's the outcome:


thanks! That's exactly what I wanted, except it's not working for me for some reason - I select an item from LOV but it is not getting populated on additional fields

and you've set the additional outputs properly? Check syntax

thank you, I got it to work by adding more than one additional column

Is there any way to get those values into the session. They are displayed on the screen but when I check the session there is nothing there... I mean P3_PROJECT_NAME etc

This might be another question you want to open a new question with, but the easiest solution is to submit the page. There are multiple solutions and they depend on what you want achieved

I did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78778706/oracle-apex-how-to-save-popup-lov-selected-values-in-the-session-state
