Oracle APEX: How to save Popup LOV selected values in the session state
I have a popup LOV with multiple columns and number of page items that get populated whenever a record is selected in the popup LOV. Which DA can I use to save the values populated into the session state before submit of the page?
I need to use those values further on the page before submitting it

Not sure I understand your quest correctly but I think this is what you want: Create a DA on change of the page item with the popup lov. Add a single action:

Type "Execute server-side code"
Code: NULL;
Page items to submit: the page items you want to get into session.

